# Does tryhaskell.org support definitions?

Tags: haskell

I try using "let" to define an expression definition, but all I get is errors.

```
> let double x = x * x
not an expression: `let double x = x * x'
```

Is there a special command I have to use or does the javascript compiler not support this functionality?

Comment: It's funny how everyone on this thread seems to think now that doubling is the same as squaring ;)

Comment: @Thomas: Haskell doesn't care about your fancy *"standard arithmetic"*! It's just that expressive!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, it does not support definitions; presumably since it's only intended as a basic introduction, and probably maintains no state between lines. As implied by its use of [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint), it simply evaluates expressions. Also unlike GHCi, it doesn't attempt to execute IO actions (thankfully!), and simply attempts to print them instead (which fails, as IO actions don't have a `Show` instance).

You can, however, do `let square x = x * x in square 42` on a single line.

By the way, Try Haskell *doesn't* use a JavaScript Haskell compiler or anything like that; it communicates with a server to evaluate the expressions you input.

All in all, it's a neat proof of concept, and a great initial hook to get people interested in Haskell, but for any kind of real use it's not suited in the least compared to something like GHCi.